# Mouse over highlighting of dates in ASP.NET calender

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, mouseover

I'm trying to add a mouse over colour change functionality to the default calender in ASP.NET. So far I've tried implementing the following code:

```
    Color col = new Color();
    col = Calendar1.DayStyle.BackColor;
    if (col != Color.Empty)
    {
        e.Cell.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.backgroundColor='pink';";
        e.Cell.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.backgroundColor='" + col + "';";
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cell.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.backgroundColor='pink';";
        e.Cell.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.backgroundColor='';";
    }
```

If I do not click on a date, things seem to be working fine. However, when I click on a date and the date background is changed to gray, the background colour is changed to pink and then back to white again. This seems like it's because somehow the line

```
    col = Calendar1.DayStyle.BackColor;
```

is not picking up the correct background colour?

Is there something I've missed here?

Comment: No, it is because the onmouserover and onmouseout event triggered after that and it becomes pink and than white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do it programmatically:

```
Color col = new Color();
col = (e.IsSelected) ? Calendar1.SelectedDayStyle.BackColor.ToString() : Calendar1.DayStyle.BackColor.ToString();

e.Cell.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.backgroundColor='pink';";
e.Cell.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.backgroundColor='" + col + "';";
```

All you need to determine if the current day is selected being rendered; I'm not sure if there is an IsSelected property; if not, replace e.IsSelected with something that does that.

Comment: I realized why my code wasn't working: it's because Calendar1.DayStyle.BackColor is the fixed background colour for unselected days. Unfortunately this means that the new problem is I cannot find a way to identify the cell your mouse hovers over. Which means there's no way to distinguish between a cell where you want onmouseout to display one colour while another cell where you want it to display another colour.

Comment: Why not?  You want only one color for unselected cells and one for the selected cell?  I don't see why the solution above might resolve that problem...

Comment: What I want is for the background colour to change from white to pink when you hover over a date and from pink to white when the mouse moves outside of the date. And the same thing for a selected date but it would be (for example) from gray to pink back to gray. However I cannot find a way to distinguish between a selected cell and nonselected cell solely through hovering your mouse over the cell itself.

Comment: Right, but you are attaching custom javascript to each cell; so from the server, you determine which cell is selected, and which cell isn't, using that selected property.  Everytime a new cell gets selected, it causes a postback, which re-renders the control, which fires the DayRender event, and updates the javascript appropriately.  Using my solution above will work.

Comment: Okay, it works if I change 
col = (e.IsSelected) ? Calendar1.SelectedDayStyle.BackColor.ToString() : Calendar1.DayStyle.BackColor.ToString();
Thanks
to
col = e.Cell.BackColor